# Dojo access form value from another widget

Tags: dojo

I have dojo form inside another widget but within the same javascript file. The form is defined with dojoAttachPoint. as `<form dojoType="dijit.form.Form" dojoAttachPoint="myForm">`

Now I want to access the form value from another widget inside the same javascript and within the same super widget. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want Widget A to access a sibling's (Widget B) attachpoint?

Answer (score 0):

From within the first Widget (the one that wants to access its sibling) I'd try:

```
// Using the dijit/registry module
var parentWidget = registry.getEnclosingWidget(this.domNode);

// Assuming the parent has the other sibling as an attachpoint, 
// but could be some other accessor or variable
var siblingWidget = parentWidget.secondSiblingAttachPoint; 

// Simple enough from here
var targetForm = siblingWidget.myForm;
```

It's a little "quick and dirty", so if the pattern needs to be reused in a lot of places I'd prefer to do something else, such as having the parent widget "inject" a reference like so:

```
this.myFirstChild.setForm(this.mySecondChild.myForm);
```

Comment: Sorry @Darien for the late reply, went with functions inside widget. The widget is written by someone else thus consulted the person and use functions within the widget and use those functions after instantiating the widget. Anyway thanks for the help even though not the solution.